# Sphinx Daemon returned error: query error: no field

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

If Set up Thinking Sphinx on my application now

Everything was working fine

Until I decide to do a conditions query with Thinking Sphinx

```
PartPriceRecord.search "50002" ,:conditions => { :supplier_id =>
"supp50002" },:star => true
```

and it reported me with the above error

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index part_price_record_core: query
error: no field 'supplier_id' found in schema
```

seeing even the Ryan Bates [Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) 
he seem to achieve the conditions clauses with "**has**" method defined
for the column

something like

```
 has :author_id
```

Reading to one of the [post](https://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/1dad41c934bfae41/bfe498c6266102b1?lnk=gst&q=%20query%20error%3a%20no%20field%20#bfe498c6266102b1) by Pate Allen (**scroll down to bottom**)

```
 :with should be used for attribute filters, and :conditions for
field queries.
```

so changing my above code **with** clause

```
PartPriceRecord.search "PartNumber50002",:with => {:supplier_id =>
"supp50002" },:star => true
```

and  I get no result which is wrong as I can **see a record for
"supplier_id" for part_number "PartNumber50002" in by database**

Now I'm confuse

why is above error appearing and also what the fundamental difference
between "**fields**" and "**attribute**"

can anyone help

BTW here my indexes definition

```
 define_index  do
   indexes part_number
   has supplier_id
 end

 sphinx_scope(:supplier) { |name|
   {:conditions => {:supplier_id => supplier}}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sphinx, currently only numeric attributes can be filtered. :supplier_id =>
"supp50002" suggests a string attribute.

I dont understand ruby or thinking-sphinx. But seeing as the underlying sphinx cant do that, I'm guessing thinking-sphinx wont allow it.

- fields, are textual columns from the original dataset. Sphinx indexes them, and they are queryable via the main 'full text query'.
- Whereas attributes, are just stored as is in the index. They are useful for retrivial[1], sorting, grouping and direct filtering. With the provisio that filtering by string attributes is not supported. can filter by other attributes

[1] Sphinx can return the values of attributes, in the resultset; whereas fields are not stored - only indexed, so you dont get them back

Comment: Your are right still attaching the links answered by pat for further reference http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/d05ad9a6a297cb25/b7a54af7f1b1d6ae?lnk=gst&q=viren#b7a54af7f1b1d6ae